# Convolution for large arrays went wrong

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, convolution

I am trying to use `ListConvolve[a, b, {1, -1}, 0]` for large arrays `a` and `b` (1024 length) to fast-up the polynomial multiplication. The problem is that I get a wrong answer each time!

I tried the following list

```
a={2.39801*10^-35, 6.01853*10^-36, 4.21297*10^-35, 8.42594*10^-35, 1.79051*10^-34, 8.42594*10^-35, 3.37038*10^-34, 1.20371*10^-35, 2.28253*10^-33, 6.43983*10^-34, 2.28704*10^-33, 3.62316*10^-33, 7.98358*10^-33, 3.62316*10^-33, 1.15556*10^-32, 1.28797*10^-33, 6.12449*10^-32, 1.68037*10^-32, 5.07904*10^-32, 6.78288*10^-32, 1.53126*10^-31, 6.79131*10^-32, 1.96108*10^-31, 3.35954*10^-32, 9.26505*10^-31, 2.47163*10^-31, 6.92251*10^-31, 8.23985*10^-31, 1.90433*10^-30, 8.27608*10^-31, 2.2595*10^-30, 4.93056*10^-31, 9.93346*10^-30, 2.58887*10^-30, 6.93086*10^-30, 7.57284*10^-30, 1.78974*10^-29, 7.63696*10^-30, 2.02018*10^-29, 5.17651*10^-30, 8.40028*10^-29, 2.16062*10^-29, 5.60615*10^-29, 5.69894*10^-29, 1.37855*10^-28, 5.77301*10^-29, 1.51871*10^-28, 4.38203*10^-29, 5.94704*10^-28, 1.53236*10^-28, 3.89434*10^-28, 3.68227*10^-28, 9.14098*10^-28, 3.75488*10^-28, 1.00955*10^-27, 3.18392*10^-28, 3.65855*10^-27, 9.60653*10^-28, 2.41749*10^-27, 2.108*10^-27, 5.3913*10^-27, 2.1727*10^-27, 6.11073*10^-27, 2.05762*10^-27, 2.00759*10^-26, 5.45364*10^-27, 1.3738*10^-26, 1.09351*10^-26, 2.89555*10^-26,1.14602*10^-26,3.42076*10^-26, 1.20748*10^-26, 1.00208*10^-25, 2.84717*10^-26, 7.25043*10^-26, 5.22799*10^-26, 1.44165*10^-25, 5.61532*10^-26, 1.78455*10^-25, 6.51882*10^-26, 4.62251*10^-25, 1.38099*10^-25, 3.58514*10^-25, 2.33577*10^-25, 6.74663*10^-25, 2.59437*10^-25, 8.7147*10^-25, 3.26542*10^-25, 1.99693*10^-24, 6.2719*10^-25, 1.67145*10^-24, 9.8716*10^-25, 2.99844*10^-24, 1.14273*10^-24, 3.99986*10^-24, 1.52727*10^-24, 8.1694*10^-24, 2.68586*10^-24, 7.38824*10^-24, 3.98932*10^-24, 1.27503*10^-23, 4.83325*10^-24, 1.73236*10^-23, 6.70475*10^-24, 3.19478*10^-23, 1.0921*10^-23, 3.11366*10^-23, 1.55617*10^-23, 5.21246*10^-23, 1.96996*10^-23, 7.10966*10^-23, 2.77732*10^-23, 1.20393*10^-22, 4.24709*10^-23, 1.25791*10^-22, 5.90142*10^-23, 2.05379*10^-22, 7.74515*10^-23, 2.77759*10^-22, 1.09216*10^-22, 4.4021*10^-22, 1.5906*10^-22, 4.89495*10^-22, 2.1851*10^-22, 7.80612*10^-22, 2.93841*10^-22, 1.03859*10^-21, 4.10292*10^-22, 1.57063*10^-21, 5.77258*10^-22, 1.84092*10^-21, 7.91228*10^-22, 2.86295*10^-21, 1.07665*10^-21, 3.74043*10^-21, 1.48108*10^-21, 5.4897*10^-21, 2.04116*10^-21, 6.70392*10^-21, 2.8013*10^-21, 1.0142*10^-20,3.81439*10^-21, 1.30597*10^-20, 5.16763*10^-21, 1.88363*10^-20, 7.0607*10^-21, 2.36542*10^-20, 9.68635*10^-21, 3.47918*10^-20, 1.30829*10^-20, 4.44629*10^-20, 1.75422*10^-20, 6.34522*10^-20, 2.39416*10^-20, 8.09151*10^-20, 3.26491*10^-20, 1.16057*10^-19, 4.3563*10^-20, 1.48198*10^-19, 5.83074*10^-20, 2.09536*10^-19, 7.95248*10^-20, 2.68894*10^-19, 1.07083*10^-19, 3.7814*10^-19, 1.41637*10^-19, 4.84265*10^-19, 1.90433*10^-19, 6.77491*10^-19, 2.58003*10^-19, 8.71011*10^-19, 3.42167*10^-19, 1.20749*10^-18, 4.52783*10^-19, 1.55087*10^-18, 6.10426*10^-19, 2.14582*10^-18, 8.15451*10^-19, 2.75922*10^-18, 1.07184*10^-18, 3.78461*10^-18, 1.42731*10^-18, 4.86837*10^-18, 1.91199*10^-18, 6.667*10^-18, 2.51728*10^-18, 8.56711*10^-18, 3.31438*10^-18, 1.1652*10^-17, 4.42012*10^-18, 1.49964*10^-17, 5.84232*10^-18, 2.03383*10^-17, 7.64967*10^-18, 2.61161*10^-17, 1.01174*10^-17, 3.52758*10^-17, 1.33807*10^-17, 4.5361*10^-17, 1.75131*10^-17, 6.09769*10^-17, 2.29916*10^-17, 7.83064*10^-17, 3.03032*10^-17, 1.05074*10^-16, 3.96736*10^-17, 1.34762*10^-16, 5.18778*10^-17, 1.80042*10^-16, 6.80523*10^-17, 2.31194*10^-16, 8.8921*10^-17, 3.07675*10^-16, 1.1607*10^-16, 3.94171*10^-16, 1.51675*10^-16, 5.24371*10^-16, 1.9758*10^-16, 6.71066*10^-16, 2.5729*10^-16, 8.87305*10^-16, 3.3538*10^-16, 1.13834*10^-15, 4.35703*10^-16, 1.503*10^-15, 5.65559*10^-16, 1.91717*10^-15, 7.35439*10^-16, 2.53042*10^-15, 9.53423*10^-16, 3.23709*10^-15, 1.23405*10^-15, 4.23967*10^-15, 1.59996*10^-15, 5.41925*10^-15, 2.06985*10^-15, 7.11798*10^-15, 2.67351*10^-15, 9.05043*10^-15, 3.45567*10^-15, 1.18421*10^-14, 4.45898*10^-15, 1.51284*10^-14, 5.75017*10^-15, 1.96852*10^-14, 7.41331*10^-15, 2.50516*10^-14, 9.53644*10^-15, 3.27277*10^-14, 1.22771*10^-14, 4.14998*10^-14, 1.58004*10^-14, 5.38982*10^-14, 2.02563*10^-14, 6.87129*10^-14, 2.60279*10^-14, 8.88776*10^-14, 3.34557*10^-14, 1.12701*10^-13, 4.27515*10^-14, 1.4642*10^-13, 5.48123*10^-14, 1.85148*10^-13, 7.0362*10^-14, 2.39024*10^-13, 8.96842*10^-14, 3.03895*10^-13, 1.14698*10^-13, 3.90851*10^-13, 1.47015*10^-13, 4.94141*10^-13, 1.86995*10^-13, 6.38812*10^-13, 2.38571*10^-13, 8.04929*10^-13, 3.05274*10^-13, 1.03421*10^-12, 3.87522*10^-13, 1.31095*10^-12, 4.93336*10^-13, 1.6773*10^-12, 6.30118*10^-13, 2.11493*10^-12, 7.98405*10^-13, 2.72031*10^-12, 1.01433*10^-12, 3.4172*10^-12, 1.29302*10^-12, 4.37221*10^-12, 1.63571*10^-12, 5.52257*10^-12, 2.074*10^-12, 7.03461*10^-12, 2.63818*10^-12, 8.8485*10^-12, 3.33275*10^-12, 1.13231*10^-11, 4.21763*10^-12, 1.41855*10^-11, 5.35408*10^-12, 1.80798*10^-11, 6.75296*10^-12, 2.27531*10^-11, 8.53187*10^-12, 2.88763*10^-11, 1.08098*10^-11, 3.62179*10^-11, 1.36094*10^-11, 4.61358*10^-11, 1.71722*10^-11, 5.76639*10^-11, 2.17113*10^-11, 7.31904*10^-11, 2.72897*10^-11, 9.18084*10^-11, 3.43873*10^-11, 1.16137*10^-10, 4.33865*10^-11, 1.45215*10^-10, 5.44586*10^-11, 1.84213*10^-10, 6.85155*10^-11, 2.29728*10^-10, 8.62772*10^-11, 2.90461*10^-10, 1.08167*10^-10, 3.6319*10^-10, 1.3584*10^-10, 4.57997*10^-10, 1.70769*10^-10, 5.7103*10^-10, 2.13832*10^-10, 7.21649*10^-10, 2.68054*10^-10, 8.97634*10^-10, 3.36472*10^-10, 1.13123*10^-9, 4.20713*10^-10, 1.41017*10^-9, 5.26613*10^-10, 1.77246*10^-9, 6.59928*10^-10, 2.20454*10^-9, 8.24046*10^-10, 2.77576*10^-9, 1.02999*10^-9, 3.44409*10^-9, 1.2886*10^-9, 4.32701*10^-9, 1.60703*10^-9, 5.37776*10^-9, 2.00575*10^-9, 6.7403*10^-9, 2.5053*10^-9, 8.36039*10^-9, 3.12065*10^-9, 1.04928*10^-8, 3.88933*10^-9, 1.2988*10^-8, 4.85025*10^-9, 1.62674*10^-8, 6.03468*10^-9, 2.01618*10^-8, 7.51018*10^-9, 2.52014*10^-8, 9.35235*10^-9, 3.11768*10^-8, 1.16207*10^-8, 3.9009*10^-8, 1.44444*10^-8, 4.81721*10^-8, 1.79605*10^-8, 6.01629*10^-8, 2.22876*10^-8, 7.43654*10^-8, 2.76708*10^-8, 9.27117*10^-8, 3.43556*10^-8, 1.14404*10^-7, 4.25821*10^-8, 1.4274*10^-7, 5.27974*10^-8, 1.75848*10^-7, 6.54684*10^-8, 2.19041*10^-7, 8.10409*10^-8, 2.70038*10^-7, 1.00362*10^-7, 3.35832*10^-7, 1.24279*10^-7, 4.13384*10^-7, 1.53667*10^-7, 5.14385*10^-7, 1.90058*10^-7, 6.32261*10^-7, 2.35052*10^-7, 7.85539*10^-7, 2.90319*10^-7, 9.66021*10^-7, 3.58576*10^-7, 1.19853*10^-6, 4.43005*10^-7, 1.47185*10^-6, 5.46449*10^-7, 1.82671*10^-6, 6.74168*10^-7, 2.24032*10^-6, 8.3191*10^-7, 2.77688*10^-6, 1.02497*10^-6, 3.40646*10^-6, 1.26307*10^-6, 4.21678*10^-6, 1.55675*10^-6, 5.1667*10^-6, 1.916*10^-6, 6.39668*10^-6, 2.35808*10^-6, 7.82799*10^-6, 2.90347*10^-6, 9.68047*10^-6, 3.56907*10^-6, 0.0000118478, 4.38823*10^-6, 0.0000146339, 5.39642*10^-6, 0.0000178907, 6.62655*10^-6, 0.0000220991, 8.13947*10^-6, 0.000026987, 9.99631*10^-6, 0.000033298, 0.0000122643, 0.0000406644, 0.0000150462, 0.0000501219, 0.0000184608, 0.000061139, 0.000022623, 0.0000753649, 0.0000277265, 0.0000918342, 0.0000339847, 0.000113076, 0.0000415985, 0.000137795, 0.0000509386, 0.000169493, 0.0000623574, 0.000206325, 0.000076269, 0.000253798, 0.0000932808, 0.000308624, 0.000114079, 0.000379263, 0.000139408, 0.000461199, 0.000170289, 0.00056616,0.000208099, 0.0006878, 0.000253997, 0.000844338, 0.000310002, 0.00102471, 0.000378398, 0.00125657, 0.000461355, 0.00152506, 0.000562642, 0.0018681, 0.000685812, 0.00226464, 0.000835341, 0.00277381, 0.00101736,0.00335835, 0.00123841, 0.00410745, 0.00150619, 0.00497057, 0.00183049, 0.00606831, 0.00222368, 0.00732628, 0.00269623, 0.00892935, 0.0032646, 0.0107411,0.00394692, 0.0130309, 0.00475261, 0.0155941, 0.00570353, 0.0187599, 0.00681256, 0.0222012, 0.00806815, 0.026332, 0.00946617, 0.0305397, 0.0109647, 0.0352501, 0.0124674, 0.039486, 0.0138631, 0.0434897,0.0149713, 0.045905, 0.0155791, 0.0471443, 0.0155791, 0.045905, 0.0149713, 0.0434897, 0.0138631, 0.039486, 0.0124674, 0.0352501, 0.0109647,0.0305397, 0.00946617, 0.026332, 0.00806815, 0.0222012, 0.00681256, 0.0187599, 0.00570353, 0.0155941, 0.00475261, 0.0130309, 0.00394692,0.0107411, 0.0032646, 0.00892935, 0.00269623, 0.00732628, 0.00222368, 0.00606831, 0.00183049, 0.00497057, 0.00150619, 0.00410745,0.00123841, 0.00335835, 0.00101736, 0.00277381, 0.000835341,0.00226464, 0.000685812, 0.0018681, 0.000562642, 0.00152506,0.000461355, 0.00125657, 0.000378398, 0.00102471, 0.000310002, 0.000844338, 0.000253997, 0.0006878, 0.000208099, 0.00056616, 0.000170289, 0.000461199, 0.000139408, 0.000379263, 0.000114079, 0.000308624, 0.0000932808, 0.000253798, 0.000076269, 0.000206325, 0.0000623574, 0.000169493, 0.0000509386, 0.000137795, 0.0000415985, 0.000113076, 0.0000339847, 0.0000918342, 0.0000277265, 0.0000753649, 0.000022623, 0.000061139, 0.0000184608, 0.0000501219, 0.0000150462, 0.0000406644, 0.0000122643, 0.000033298, 9.99631*10^-6, 0.000026987, 8.13947*10^-6, 0.0000220991, 6.62655*10^-6, 0.0000178907, 5.39642*10^-6, 0.0000146339, 4.38823*10^-6, 0.0000118478, 3.56907*10^-6, 9.68047*10^-6, 2.90347*10^-6, 7.82799*10^-6, 2.35808*10^-6, 6.39668*10^-6, 1.916*10^-6, 5.1667*10^-6, 1.55675*10^-6, 4.21678*10^-6, 1.26307*10^-6, 3.40646*10^-6, 1.02497*10^-6, 2.77688*10^-6, 8.3191*10^-7, 2.24032*10^-6, 6.74168*10^-7, 1.82671*10^-6, 5.46449*10^-7, 1.47185*10^-6, 4.43005*10^-7, 1.19853*10^-6, 3.58576*10^-7, 9.66021*10^-7, 2.90319*10^-7, 7.85539*10^-7, 2.35052*10^-7, 6.32261*10^-7, 1.90058*10^-7, 5.14385*10^-7, 1.53667*10^-7, 4.13384*10^-7, 1.24279*10^-7, 3.35832*10^-7, 1.00362*10^-7, 2.70038*10^-7, 8.10409*10^-8, 2.19041*10^-7, 6.54684*10^-8, 1.75848*10^-7, 5.27974*10^-8, 1.4274*10^-7, 4.25821*10^-8, 1.14404*10^-7, 3.43556*10^-8, 9.27117*10^-8, 2.76708*10^-8, 7.43654*10^-8, 2.22876*10^-8, 6.01629*10^-8, 1.79605*10^-8, 4.81721*10^-8, 1.44444*10^-8, 3.9009*10^-8, 1.16207*10^-8, 3.11768*10^-8, 9.35235*10^-9, 2.52014*10^-8, 7.51018*10^-9, 2.01618*10^-8, 6.03468*10^-9, 1.62674*10^-8, 4.85025*10^-9, 1.2988*10^-8, 3.88933*10^-9, 1.04928*10^-8, 3.12065*10^-9, 8.36039*10^-9, 2.5053*10^-9, 6.7403*10^-9, 2.00575*10^-9, 5.37776*10^-9, 1.60703*10^-9, 4.32701*10^-9, 1.2886*10^-9, 3.44409*10^-9, 1.02999*10^-9, 2.77576*10^-9, 8.24046*10^-10, 2.20454*10^-9, 6.59928*10^-10, 1.77246*10^-9, 5.26613*10^-10, 1.41017*10^-9, 4.20713*10^-10, 1.13123*10^-9, 3.36472*10^-10, 8.97634*10^-10, 2.68054*10^-10, 7.21649*10^-10, 2.13832*10^-10, 5.7103*10^-10, 1.70769*10^-10, 4.57997*10^-10, 1.3584*10^-10, 3.6319*10^-10, 1.08167*10^-10, 2.90461*10^-10, 8.62772*10^-11, 2.29728*10^-10, 6.85155*10^-11, 1.84213*10^-10, 5.44586*10^-11, 1.45215*10^-10, 4.33865*10^-11, 1.16137*10^-10, 3.43873*10^-11, 9.18084*10^-11, 2.72897*10^-11, 7.31904*10^-11, 2.17113*10^-11, 5.76639*10^-11, 1.71722*10^-11, 4.61358*10^-11, 1.36094*10^-11, 3.62179*10^-11, 1.08098*10^-11, 2.88763*10^-11, 8.53187*10^-12, 2.27531*10^-11, 6.75296*10^-12, 1.80798*10^-11, 5.35408*10^-12, 1.41855*10^-11, 4.21763*10^-12, 1.13231*10^-11, 3.33275*10^-12, 8.8485*10^-12, 2.63818*10^-12, 7.03461*10^-12, 2.074*10^-12, 5.52257*10^-12, 1.63571*10^-12, 4.37221*10^-12, 1.29302*10^-12, 3.4172*10^-12, 1.01433*10^-12, 2.72031*10^-12, 7.98405*10^-13, 2.11493*10^-12, 6.30118*10^-13, 1.6773*10^-12, 4.93336*10^-13, 1.31095*10^-12, 3.87522*10^-13, 1.03421*10^-12, 3.05274*10^-13, 8.04929*10^-13, 2.38571*10^-13, 6.38812*10^-13, 1.86995*10^-13, 4.94141*10^-13, 1.47015*10^-13, 3.90851*10^-13, 1.14698*10^-13, 3.03895*10^-13, 8.96842*10^-14, 2.39024*10^-13, 7.0362*10^-14, 1.85148*10^-13, 5.48123*10^-14, 1.4642*10^-13, 4.27515*10^-14, 1.12701*10^-13, 3.34557*10^-14, 8.88776*10^-14, 2.60279*10^-14, 6.87129*10^-14, 2.02563*10^-14, 5.38982*10^-14, 1.58004*10^-14, 4.14998*10^-14, 1.22771*10^-14, 3.27277*10^-14, 9.53644*10^-15, 2.50516*10^-14, 7.41331*10^-15, 1.96852*10^-14, 5.75017*10^-15, 1.51284*10^-14, 4.45898*10^-15, 1.18421*10^-14, 3.45567*10^-15, 9.05043*10^-15, 2.67351*10^-15, 7.11798*10^-15, 2.06985*10^-15, 5.41925*10^-15, 1.59996*10^-15, 4.23967*10^-15, 1.23405*10^-15, 3.23709*10^-15, 9.53423*10^-16, 2.53042*10^-15, 7.35439*10^-16, 1.91717*10^-15, 5.65559*10^-16, 1.503*10^-15, 4.35703*10^-16, 1.13834*10^-15, 3.3538*10^-16, 8.87305*10^-16, 2.5729*10^-16, 6.71066*10^-16, 1.9758*10^-16, 5.24371*10^-16, 1.51675*10^-16, 3.94171*10^-16, 1.1607*10^-16, 3.07675*10^-16, 8.8921*10^-17, 2.31194*10^-16, 6.80523*10^-17, 1.80042*10^-16, 5.18778*10^-17, 1.34762*10^-16, 3.96736*10^-17, 1.05074*10^-16, 3.03032*10^-17, 7.83064*10^-17, 2.29916*10^-17, 6.09769*10^-17, 1.75131*10^-17, 4.5361*10^-17, 1.33807*10^-17, 3.52758*10^-17, 1.01174*10^-17, 2.61161*10^-17, 7.64967*10^-18, 2.03383*10^-17, 5.84232*10^-18, 1.49964*10^-17, 4.42012*10^-18, 1.1652*10^-17, 3.31438*10^-18, 8.56711*10^-18, 2.51728*10^-18, 6.667*10^-18, 1.91199*10^-18, 4.86837*10^-18, 1.42731*10^-18, 3.78461*10^-18, 1.07184*10^-18, 2.75922*10^-18, 8.15451*10^-19, 2.14582*10^-18, 6.10426*10^-19, 1.55087*10^-18, 4.52783*10^-19, 1.20749*10^-18, 3.42167*10^-19, 8.71011*10^-19, 2.58003*10^-19, 6.77491*10^-19, 1.90433*10^-19, 4.84265*10^-19, 1.41637*10^-19, 3.7814*10^-19, 1.07083*10^-19, 2.68894*10^-19, 7.95248*10^-20, 2.09536*10^-19, 5.83074*10^-20, 1.48198*10^-19, 4.3563*10^-20, 1.16057*10^-19, 3.26491*10^-20, 8.09151*10^-20, 2.39416*10^-20, 6.34522*10^-20, 1.75422*10^-20, 4.44629*10^-20, 1.30829*10^-20, 3.47918*10^-20, 9.68635*10^-21, 2.36542*10^-20, 7.0607*10^-21, 1.88363*10^-20, 5.16763*10^-21, 1.30597*10^-20, 3.81439*10^-21, 1.0142*10^-20, 2.8013*10^-21, 6.70392*10^-21, 2.04116*10^-21, 5.4897*10^-21, 1.48108*10^-21, 3.74043*10^-21, 1.07665*10^-21, 2.86295*10^-21, 7.91228*10^-22, 1.84092*10^-21, 5.77258*10^-22, 1.57063*10^-21, 4.10292*10^-22, 1.03859*10^-21, 2.93841*10^-22, 7.80612*10^-22, 2.1851*10^-22, 4.89495*10^-22, 1.5906*10^-22, 4.4021*10^-22, 1.09216*10^-22, 2.77759*10^-22, 7.74515*10^-23, 2.05379*10^-22, 5.90142*10^-23, 1.25791*10^-22, 4.24709*10^-23, 1.20393*10^-22, 2.77732*10^-23, 7.10966*10^-23, 1.96996*10^-23, 5.21246*10^-23, 1.55617*10^-23, 3.11366*10^-23, 1.0921*10^-23, 3.19478*10^-23, 6.70475*10^-24, 1.73236*10^-23, 4.83325*10^-24, 1.27503*10^-23, 3.98932*10^-24, 7.38824*10^-24, 2.68586*10^-24, 8.1694*10^-24, 1.52727*10^-24, 3.99986*10^-24, 1.14273*10^-24, 2.99844*10^-24, 9.8716*10^-25, 1.67145*10^-24, 6.2719*10^-25, 1.99693*10^-24, 3.26542*10^-25, 8.7147*10^-25, 2.59437*10^-25, 6.74663*10^-25, 2.33577*10^-25, 3.58514*10^-25, 1.38099*10^-25, 4.62251*10^-25, 6.51882*10^-26, 1.78455*10^-25, 5.61532*10^-26, 1.44165*10^-25, 5.22799*10^-26, 7.25043*10^-26, 2.84717*10^-26, 1.00208*10^-25, 1.20748*10^-26, 3.42076*10^-26, 1.14602*10^-26, 2.89555*10^-26, 1.09351*10^-26, 1.3738*10^-26, 5.45364*10^-27, 2.00759*10^-26, 2.05762*10^-27, 6.11073*10^-27, 2.1727*10^-27, 5.3913*10^-27, 2.108*10^-27, 2.41749*10^-27, 9.60653*10^-28, 3.65855*10^-27, 3.18392*10^-28, 1.00955*10^-27, 3.75488*10^-28, 9.14098*10^-28, 3.68227*10^-28, 3.89434*10^-28, 1.53236*10^-28, 5.94704*10^-28, 4.38203*10^-29, 1.51871*10^-28, 5.77301*10^-29, 1.37855*10^-28, 5.69894*10^-29, 5.60615*10^-29, 2.16062*10^-29, 8.40028*10^-29, 5.17651*10^-30, 2.02018*10^-29, 7.63696*10^-30, 1.78974*10^-29, 7.57284*10^-30, 6.93086*10^-30, 2.58887*10^-30, 9.93346*10^-30, 4.93056*10^-31, 2.2595*10^-30, 8.27608*10^-31, 1.90433*10^-30, 8.23985*10^-31, 6.92251*10^-31, 2.47163*10^-31, 9.26505*10^-31, 3.35954*10^-32, 1.96108*10^-31, 6.79131*10^-32, 1.53126*10^-31, 6.78288*10^-32, 5.07904*10^-32, 1.68037*10^-32, 6.12449*10^-32, 1.28797*10^-33, 1.15556*10^-32, 3.62316*10^-33, 7.98358*10^-33, 3.62316*10^-33, 2.28704*10^-33, 6.43983*10^-34, 2.28253*10^-33, 1.20371*10^-35, 3.37038*10^-34, 8.42594*10^-35, 1.79051*10^-34, 8.42594*10^-35, 4.21297*10^-35, 6.01853*10^-36, 2.39801*10^-35}
```

for `a=b`. After `ListConvolve[a,a,{1,-1},0]` is done, the answer should be something like that (the coefficient list of `a(X)*a(X)`):

```
{5.75044*10^-70, 2.8865*10^-70, 2.05677*10^-69, 4.54821*10^-69, 1.13765*10^-68, 1.3296*10^-68, 3.9365*10^-68, 4.19074*10^-68, 1.84273*10^-67, 1.46345*10^-67, 4.39585*10^-67, 7.01315*10^-67, 1.66074*10^-66, 1.58394*10^-66, 4.34734*10^-66, 4.02345*10^-66, 1.47736*10^-65, 1.1679*10^-65, 2.90883*10^-65, 4.01298*10^-65, 9.16399*10^-65, 8.02545*10^-65, 2.03953*10^-64, 1.76336*10^-64, 5.97809*10^-64, 4.59024*10^-64, 1.04704*10^-63, 1.31937*10^-63, 2.93375*10^-63, 2.44813*10^-63, 5.85701*10^-63, 4.86552*10^-63, 1.56721*10^-62, 1.17025*10^-62, 2.53363*10^-62, 2.9934*10^-62, 6.52251*10^-62, 5.26884*10^-62, 1.20336*10^-61, 9.741*10^-62, 3.02025*10^-61, 2.20219*10^-61, 4.60303*10^-61, 5.17734*10^-61, 1.11044*10^-60, 8.75554*10^-61, 1.92863*10^-60, 1.5336*10^-60, 4.61101*10^-60, 3.29621*10^-60, 6.71537*10^-60, 7.2611*10^-60, 1.53803*10^-59, 1.18968*10^-59, 2.54683*10^-59, 1.99936*10^-59, 5.85557*10^-59, 4.11894*10^-59, 8.2288*10^-59, 8.60824*10^-59, 1.80531*10^-58, 1.3746*10^-58, 2.87716*10^-58, 2.2371*10^-58, 6.39911*10^-58, 4.44427*10^-58, 8.7441*10^-58, 8.88667*10^-58, 1.84887*10^-57, 1.3893*10^-57, 2.85746*10^-57, 2.20517*10^-57, 6.16916*10^-57, 4.24388*10^-57, 8.25077*10^-57, 8.16737*10^-57, 1.68832*10^-56, 1.25457*10^-56, 2.54658*10^-56, 1.95314*10^-56, 5.34637*10^-56, 3.65402*10^-56, 7.03938*10^-56, 6.7972*10^-56, 1.39776*10^-55, 1.02892*10^-55, 2.06908*10^-55, 1.57834*10^-55, 4.22659*10^-55, 2.87816*10^-55, 5.50765*10^-55, 5.1916*10^-55, 1.06305*10^-54, 7.76366*10^-55, 1.55183*10^-54, 1.17785*10^-54, 3.08398*10^-54, 2.09785*10^-54, 3.99622*10^-54, 3.67853*10^-54, 7.506*10^-54, 5.44607*10^-54, 1.08509*10^-53, 8.19612*10^-54, 2.0969*10^-53, 1.4281*10^-53, 2.71319*10^-53, 2.43935*10^-53, 4.96326*10^-53, 3.58207*10^-53, 7.13025*10^-53, 5.36012*10^-53, 1.33918*10^-52, 9.14834*10^-53, 1.73627*10^-52, 1.52501*10^-52, 3.09572*10^-52, 2.22481*10^-52, 4.43172*10^-52, 3.31585*10^-52, 8.08741*10^-52, 5.54923*10^-52, 1.05356*10^-51, 9.04352*10^-52, 1.83246*10^-51, 1.31261*10^-51, 2.61928*10^-51, 1.95075*10^-51, 4.64483*10^-51, 3.20406*10^-51, 6.09187*10^-51, 5.11368*10^-51, 1.03472*10^-50, 7.39333*10^-51, 1.47863*10^-50, 1.09635*10^-50, 2.54954*10^-50, 1.76878*10^-50, 3.37064*10^-50, 2.76952*10^-50, 5.59824*10^-50, 3.99262*10^-50, 8.00271*10^-50, 5.90884*10^-50, 1.34318*10^-49, 9.37149*10^-50, 1.79101*10^-49, 1.44221*10^-49, 2.91312*10^-49, 2.07477*10^-49, 4.166*10^-49, 3.06398*10^-49, 6.81701*10^-49, 4.78134*10^-49, 9.16758*10^-49, 7.24543*10^-49, 1.4627*10^-48, 1.04072*10^-48, 2.0919*10^-48, 1.533*10^-48, 3.34375*10^-48, 2.35595*10^-48, 4.53287*10^-48, 3.52192*10^-48, 7.10649*10^-48, 5.0526*10^-48, 1.01578*10^-47, 7.41924*10^-48, 1.5895*10^-47, 1.12406*10^-47, 2.17026*10^-47, 1.66067*10^-47, 3.34893*10^-47, 2.37967*10^-47, 4.78068*10^-47, 3.48109*10^-47, 7.34038*10^-47, 5.2051*10^-47, 1.00837*10^-46, 7.61262*10^-47, 1.53395*10^-46, 1.08946*10^-46, 2.18532*10^-46, 1.58668*10^-46, 3.3*10^-46, 2.34421*10^-46, 4.55569*10^-46, 3.39917*10^-46, 6.84163*10^-46, 4.85688*10^-46, 9.72091*10^-46, 7.03851*10^-46, 1.44688*10^-45, 1.02875*10^-45, 2.00486*10^-45, 1.4809*10^-45, 2.97611*10^-45, 2.11171*10^-45, 4.21527*10^-45, 3.04389*10^-45, 6.1966*10^-45, 4.40668*10^-45, 8.60803*10^-45, 6.30414*10^-45, 1.26446*10^-44, 8.96696*10^-45, 1.78471*10^-44, 1.28533*10^-44, 2.59581*10^-44, 1.84525*10^-44, 3.61113*10^-44, 2.62556*10^-44, 5.25399*10^-44, 3.72343*10^-44, 7.38878*10^-44, 5.30721*10^-44, 1.06492*10^-43, 7.56364*10^-44, 1.48208*10^-43, 1.07103*10^-43, 2.13758*10^-43, 1.51369*10^-43, 2.99514*10^-43, 2.14567*10^-43, 4.28294*10^-43, 3.03849*10^-43, 5.95802*10^-43, 4.28347*10^-43, 8.5248*10^-43, 6.03122*10^-43, 1.19021*10^-42, 8.50421*10^-43, 1.69031*10^-42, 1.19756*10^-42, 2.3486*10^-42, 1.68113*10^-42, 3.33595*10^-42, 2.35773*10^-42, 4.64153*10^-42, 3.30796*10^-42, 6.55184*10^-42, 4.63506*10^-42, 9.08714*10^-42, 6.48018*10^-42, 1.28216*10^-41, 9.05161*10^-42, 1.77809*10^-41, 1.26407*10^-41, 2.49617*10^-41, 1.76319*10^-41, 3.45427*10^-41, 2.45526*10^-41, 4.84436*10^-41, 3.41579*10^-41, 6.69701*10^-41, 4.7496*10^-41, 9.35432*10^-41, 6.59715*10^-41, 1.29113*10^-40, 9.15081*10^-41, 1.80075*10^-40, 1.26809*10^-40, 2.48189*10^-40, 1.75614*10^-40, 3.45044*10^-40, 2.42961*10^-40, 4.74917*10^-40, 3.35728*10^-40, 6.59054*10^-40, 4.63491*10^-40, 9.05664*10^-40, 6.39424*10^-40, 1.25354*10^-39, 8.81298*10^-40, 1.72036*10^-39, 1.21333*10^-39, 2.37646*10^-39, 1.66902*10^-39, 3.25625*10^-39, 2.29419*10^-39, 4.48819*10^-39, 3.15056*10^-39, 6.14148*10^-39, 4.32225*10^-39, 8.44801*10^-39, 5.92499*10^-39, 1.15424*10^-38, 8.11593*10^-39, 1.58462*10^-38, 1.11067*10^-38, 2.162*10^-38, 1.51859*10^-38, 2.96236*10^-38, 2.07477*10^-38, 4.03593*10^-38, 2.83244*10^-38, 5.51995*10^-38, 3.86333*10^-38, 7.50962*10^-38, 5.26512*10^-38, 1.0252*10^-37, 7.17033*10^-38, 1.39281*10^-37, 9.75715*10^-38, 1.89815*10^-37, 1.3266*10^-37, 2.57509*10^-37, 1.80233*10^-37, 3.50334*10^-37, 2.44687*10^-37, 4.74633*10^-37, 3.31928*10^-37, 6.44652*10^-37, 4.49921*10^-37, 8.7215*10^-37, 6.09427*10^-37, 1.18265*10^-36, 8.24878*10^-37, 1.59788*10^-36, 1.11564*10^-36, 2.16328*10^-36, 1.5078*10^-36, 2.91885*10^-36, 2.0364*10^-36, 3.94562*10^-36, 2.74832*10^-36, 5.31672*10^-36, 3.70642*10^-36, 7.176*10^-36, 4.9951*10^-36, 9.65695*10^-36, 6.72724*10^-36, 1.30149*10^-35, 9.05364*10^-36, 1.74919*10^-35, 1.21762*10^-35, 2.35399*10^-35, 1.63648*10^-35, 3.1597*10^-35, 2.19795*10^-35, 4.2462*10^-35, 2.95005*10^-35, 5.69237*10^-35, 3.95691*10^-35, 7.63909*10^-35, 5.30399*10^-35, 1.02281*10^-34, 7.105*10^-35, 1.37073*10^-34, 9.51137*10^-35, 1.83304*10^-34, 1.27247*10^-34, 2.45328*10^-34, 1.70129*10^-34, 3.27672*10^-34, 2.27317*10^-34, 4.37973*10^-34, 3.03539*10^-34, 5.84276*10^-34, 4.0507*10^-34, 7.79951*10^-34, 5.4023*10^-34, 1.03926*10^-33, 7.20047*10^-34, 1.38556*10^-33, 9.59139*10^-34, 1.84406*10^-33, 1.27686*10^-33, 2.45549*10^-33, 1.69881*10^-33, 3.26428*10^-33, 2.25886*10^-33, 4.34131*10^-33, 3.00179*10^-33, 5.7647*10^-33, 3.98674*10^-33, 7.65755*10^-33, 5.29182*10^-33, 1.01568*10^-32, 7.02009*10^-33, 1.3476*10^-32, 9.30751*10^-33, 1.78545*10^-32, 1.23333*10^-32, 2.36617*10^-32, 1.63336*10^-32, 3.13154*10^-32, 2.16194*10^-32, 4.14536*10^-32, 2.85999*10^-32, 5.48033*10^-32, 3.78135*10^-32, 7.24642*10^-32, 4.99682*10^-32, 9.56984*10^-32, 6.59941*10^-32, 1.26399*10^-31, 8.71132*10^-32, 1.66751*10^-31, 1.1493*10^-31, 2.20005*10^-31, 1.51547*10^-31, 2.89939*10^-31, 1.99728*10^-31, 3.82128*10^-31, 2.63088*10^-31, 5.0308*10^-31, 3.46369*10^-31, 6.6234*10^-31, 4.55778*10^-31, 8.71105*10^-31, 5.99442*10^-31, 1.14568*10^-30, 7.87988*10^-31, 1.50529*10^-30, 1.03531*10^-30, 1.97773*10^-30, 1.35959*10^-30, 2.59594*10^-30, 1.78455*10^-30, 3.40726*10^-30, 2.34118*10^-30, 4.46796*10^-30, 3.06992*10^-30, 5.85853*10^-30, 4.02354*10^-30, 7.67494*10^-30, 5.27083*10^-30, 1.00538*10^-29, 6.90146*10^-30, 1.31584*10^-29, 9.03225*10^-30, 1.72201*10^-29, 1.18153*10^-29, 2.25165*10^-29, 1.54486*10^-29, 2.94388*10^-29, 2.01896*10^-29, 3.84577*10^-29, 2.63734*10^-29, 5.02336*10^-29,3.44352*10^-29, 6.55632*10^-29, 4.49408*10^-29, 8.55594*10^-29, 5.86246*10^-29, 1.11568*10^-28, 7.64401*10^-29, 1.45462*10^-28, 9.96249*10^-29, 1.89511*10^-28, 1.29783*10^-28, 2.46861*10^-28, 1.68996*10^-28, 3.21331*10^-28, 2.1996*10^-28, 4.18198*10^-28, 2.86166*10^-28, 5.43881*10^-28, 3.72136*10^-28, 7.07213*10^-28, 4.83725*10^-28, 9.18961*10^-28, 6.28502*10^-28, 1.19389*10^-27, 8.16259*10^-28, 1.55004*10^-27, 1.05966*10^-27, 2.01204*10^-27, 1.37505*10^-27, 2.61005*10^-27, 1.78355*10^-27, 3.38513*10^-27, 2.31245*10^-27, 4.38757*10^-27, 2.99695*10^-27, 5.68573*10^-27, 3.88244*10^-27, 7.36339*10^-27, 5.0275*10^-27, 9.53409*10^-27, 6.50761*10^-27, 1.23372*10^-26, 8.42003*10^-27, 1.59611*10^-26, 1.08901*10^-26, 2.06372*10^-26, 1.4079*10^-26, 2.66776*10^-26, 1.81945*10^-26, 3.44658*10^-26, 2.35036*10^-26, 4.4518*10^-26, 3.035*10^-26, 5.74693*10^-26, 3.91752*10^-26, 7.41721*10^-26, 5.05468*10^-26, 9.56758*10^-26, 6.51939*10^-26, 1.23386*10^-25, 8.40528*10^-26, 1.59036*10^-25, 1.08326*10^-25, 2.04938*10^-25, 1.39554*10^-25, 2.63949*10^-25, 1.79717*10^-25, 3.39873*10^-25, 2.31352*10^-25, 4.37407*10^-25, 2.97709*10^-25, 5.628*10^-25, 3.82955*10^-25, 7.23769*10^-25, 4.92428*10^-25, 9.30558*10^-25, 6.32962*10^-25, 1.19583*10^-24, 8.133*10^-25,1.53636*10^-24, 1.04464*10^-24,...}
```

but it didn't work! I am obtaining instead

```
{0., -4.33681*10^-19, -4.33681*10^-19, 8.67362*10^-19, 8.67362*10^-19,8.67362*10^-19, -8.67362*10^-19, 8.67362*10^-19, -4.33681*10^-19, 0., 0., -1.73472*10^-18, -4.33681*10^-19, 0., -4.33681*10^-19, 4.33681*10^-19, -4.33681*10^-19,8.67362*10^-19, -4.33681*10^-19, -1.30104*10^-18, -4.33681*10^-19, 0., -8.67362*10^-19, -8.67362*10^-19, -4.33681*10^-19, -6.50521*10^-19, 0., 2.1684*10^-19, -2.1684*10^-19, -8.67362*10^-19, -2.1684*10^-19, 2.1684*10^-19, -2.1684*10^-19, -5.42101*10^-19, -5.42101*10^-19,-1.0842*10^-19, -2.1684*10^-19, 0., -2.1684*10^-19, -1.0842*10^-18, 0.,-6.50521*10^-19, -3.25261*10^-19, -2.1684*10^-19, -3.25261*10^-19, -7.04731*10^-19, -5.42101*10^-20, -7.58942*10^-19, -1.0842*10^-19, -7.04731*10^-19, -4.33681*10^-19, -5.42101*10^-19, -2.71051*10^-20, -7.86047*10^-19, -1.6263*10^-19, -1.00289*10^-18, -2.98156*10^-19, -9.48677*10^-19, -2.71051*10^-20, -1.11131*10^-18, 2.43945*10^-19, -1.35525*10^-18, 0., -8.53809*10^-19, -1.35525*10^-19, -1.02999*10^-18, 8.13152*10^-20, -6.36969*10^-19, 2.91379*10^-19, -9.89334*10^-19, -1.35525*10^-20, -8.19928*10^-19, 8.13152*10^-20, -6.1664*10^-19, -1.49078*10^-19, -2.77827*10^-19, 2.67662*10^-19, -8.1654*10^-19, 9.14796*10^-19, -4.30293*10^-19, 2.43945*10^-19, -5.42101*10^-19, 1.76183*10^-19, -3.11708*10^-19, 2.55804*10^-19, -9.77476*10^-19, 3.5406*10^-19, -3.82859*10^-19, 3.37119*10^-19, -2.30393*10^-19, 6.94567*10^-20, -5.52265*10^-19, 1.27902*10^-19, -7.53012*10^-19, 8.42798*10^-19, -3.49825*10^-19, ... }
```

which is not true.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: You already posted this question once [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/243868/12). Several of us asked for clarifications, but instead of answering the questions, you deleted the original post and re-posted it. This is not going to help you get an answer, quite the contrary. Please do not keep deleting and re-posting questions. Instead, provide the requested clarifications.

Comment: @Szabolcs I made the necessary clarifications! Is it still not clear? I just want to know why the 'ListConvolution' function doesn't work properly for large arrays? Thank you!

Comment: `ListConvolve` in this case will use `Fourier`. That latter, with machine precision, is not going to handle the scale differences in the input to the precision you might like. The following will give the expected result, albeit not so fast: `In[154]:= abig = SetPrecision[a, 100];
a2 = N@ListConvolve[abig, abig, {1, -1}, 0];
a2[[1 ;; 5]]

Out[156]= {5.75045*10^-70, 2.8865*10^-70, 2.05677*10^-69, 
 4.54822*10^-69, 1.13765*10^-68}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks a lot!